# WP7 MdeiaPlayer Event for video finished playing

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player

I am using MediaPlayerLauncher for playing video. How do we get some notification when the MediaPlayerLauncher is opened() and the video is finished it's playback or the MediaPlayerLauncher is closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't explicit know if it's from a video or another navigation, but the [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event will tell you when the user returns to your page.

Comment: You can save a flag to the PhoneApplicationPage.State property, or to Isolated Storage, when the video is launched. Then, in the OnNavigatedTo section, you can check if the flag is set (in which case the user is returning from the video, otherwise they're returning from another page). You can then reset the flag.

Comment: Yep, that would be a good way to identify it from other navigation events.

Answer (score 0):

By using the built in MediaPlayer you are giving up a lot of control to playback. If you really must`*` know when a video has finished playing you should use the MediaElement and detect the [MediaEnded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaended%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) event.

`*`  The end of a movie is typically a grey area. Does it include any ending credits? Is it when the user has watched "enough"? Is a certain percentage through the video sufficient ?